# Recibir Array en Controller Laravel

Tags: laravel

Cuando recojo los valores del formulario en el controlador, me salta el null y no sé porqué

```
 <body>
            <form action="FormTablaJuego" method="POST">
                {!! csrf_field(); !!}
                @for($i=0;$i<11;$i++) 
                 {!! \Session::get('num'); !!} * {!! $i !!} = <input type='text' name='caja[]' value=''><br/>
                @endfor
                <input type='submit' value='Comprobar' name="btncomprobar"><br/>
                <input type='submit' value='Rendirse' name="btnrendirse"><br/>
            </form>
         </body>
```

En la ruta:

```
Route::post('FormTablaJuego' ,'EduController@jugar');
```

En el controlador:

```
 public function jugar(Request $request)
    {
        echo var_dump($request->get('caja[]'));
    }
```

Lo muestro en el controlador para saber que es correcto antes de seguir. Pero devuelve **NULL**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes que poner el "[]" es simplemente `$request->get('caja')` o `$request->caja`

Answer (score -1):

Laravel ofrece una mejor forma de imprimir los datos en pantalla y es utilizando `dd()`, deberías usarlo en vez del `echo` y el `var_dump()`.

Deberías hacer un `dd($request->all())` para que puedas verificar que el controlador si está recibiendo tus datos y como los está recibiendo, una vez que verifiques esto podrías hacer un `dd($request->get('caja'))` ya que creería yo que es así como lo deberías de recibir.